# Trying to access JavaScript object properties, getting different results

Tags: javascript, oop

Here is the pseudo-code in question: https://jsfiddle.net/yzps2gef/40/

I'm trying to understand why I cannot access an object's properties directly in one scenario (see ISSUE #1 in comments) but I can in another scenario (see ISSUE #2 in comments).  I'm failing to see the difference between the two.  Thanks!

Here's the fiddle code:

```
window.DataStore = function () {
    var url = new Url(),
        filters = new Filters(),
        orderBy,
        orderByDir,
        setOrderBy = function (x, y) {
            orderBy = x;
            orderByDir = y;
        },
        getOrderBy = function () {
            return orderBy;
        },
        getOrderByDir = function () {
            return orderByDir;
        };

    return {
        url: url,
        filters: filters,
        orderBy: orderBy,
        orderByDir: orderByDir,
        setOrderBy: setOrderBy,
        getOrderBy: getOrderBy,
        getOrderByDir: getOrderByDir
    };
};

window.Url = function () {
    var get = function (ds) {
        var url = 'xyz.php';

        console.log(ds);

        // ISSUE #1: These do not work.  It results in: xyz.php?orderby=undefined&orderbydir=undefined.
        // Why can't I access them directly like I do below with the dataStore.filters.someFilterOption?
        url = url + '?orderby=' + ds.orderBy;
        url = url + '&orderbydir=' + ds.orderByDir;

        // These work when I use the "get" functions.
        // url = url + '?orderby=' + ds.getOrderBy();
        // url = url + '&orderbydir=' + ds.getOrderByDir();

        return url;
    }

    return {
        get: get
    };
};

window.Filters = function () {
    var someFilterOption = 0;

    return {
        someFilterOption: someFilterOption
    };
};

window.Grid = function () {
    var dataStore = new DataStore(),
        doSearch = function () {
            console.log(dataStore.url.get(dataStore));
        },
        render = function () {
            doSearch();
            // ISSUE #2: Why can I access this one directly but not the order bys?
            if (dataStore.filters.someFilterOption) {
                console.log('Why was I able to read this one (dataStore.filters.someFilterOption) directly and not have to have a getSomeFilterOption() function to read it?  But when it comes to the orderBy and orderByDir above I cannot read them directly.');
            }
        }

    return {
        dataStore: dataStore,
        render: render
    };
};

window.MyReUsableGrid = function () {
    var grid = new Grid(),
        showSomeFilterOption = function () {
            grid.dataStore.filters.someFilterOption = 1;
        },
        render = function () {
            grid.render();
        };

    grid.dataStore.setOrderBy(4, 'asc');

    return {
        showSomeFilterOption: showSomeFilterOption,
        render: render
    };
};

// The Screen
var myGridScreen = new MyReUsableGrid();
myGridScreen.showSomeFilterOption();
myGridScreen.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when your object gets returned from the function this line gets evaluated:

```
 orderBy: orderBy,
```

And as the variable `orderBy` isnt set yet it is actually:

```
 orderBy: undefined
```

Now later you call `setOrderBy` and set the internal variable `orderBy` to a value which you can expose through the getter, but that doesnt get reflected to the objects property.

---

IMO the whole thing should be restructured so that the methods work with their context:

```
 window.DataStore = () => ({
    url: new Url(),
    filters: new Filters(),
    applyOrder(order, dir) {
        this.orderBy = order;
        this.orderByDir = dir;
    },
 });
```

That way you dont need getters at all.

Comment: Thanks.  But then why does `grid.dataStore.filters.someFilterOption = 1;` work?  It is set after the object is returned as well, and it doesn't have a getter function and it's not set using `this` but I can access it directly in that IF statement and it yields 1, not 0.

Comment: @gfrobenius because you mutate the exported object and access the exported object. The internal variable is not really involved

Comment: This is working, thank you but I was trying to stick w/ the revealing pattern, less usage of `this` & very easy to see everything that is public by just looking at the `return`. In your example, I can't do that. If I set the orderbys your way then I must remove them from the VAR stmnt & the `return` because they are now created public right there inside the `applyOrder` func. Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't I do exactly what your answer says, except remove the `this`, & keep them init'ed in the VAR stmnt, & keep them in the `return`, & that would have the same end result? Thx

Comment: Ah, never mind. If I do that then I need the getters. I actually prefer that way (the reveal pattern, everything private except what I reveal in the return, then just use all setters and getters).  I think I'll take that approach.  But will mark this as the answer because you helped me understand this which is what I was looking for.  Thanks!